How to map header to bucket name in API gateway S3 integration
I am using AWS apigateway to proxy file upload to S3 bucket. I want to map a incoming header to a bucket name in the integration.

Under the method request > HTTP request headers I am adding X-Api-Key with the required true and caching true.
under integration request > URL request headers parameters adding
Name  = X-Api-Key
Mapped from = method.request.header.X-Api-Key

path override as {X-Api-Key}/{proxy}
X-Api-Key is not interpreted from the header and throws
Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 44: https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/{X-Api-Key}/orders/122.csv
However the proxy works perfect without the X-Api-Key path.
